# How to find the id of the menu elements in Odoo?

Tags: menuitem, odoo-8, odoo

When I activate developer mode, I'm unable to locate the menu ID that I can use as a parent in a new menu item tag. Is there a specific location within the configuration where I can find it?

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33448098/customizing-accounting-and-finance-module-in-odoo/33448441#33448441

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of declaring a menuitem:

- With a shortcut. You can search the string that you see in the interface. This string is going to be the attribute `name` of the menuitem. If you want to search the menuitem of this example you should search the string `name="Human readable name"` in the Odoo source code:

```xml
<menuitem id="menu_human_readable_name" 
          name="Human readable name" 
          parent="base.menu_custom" 
          sequence="10" 
          action="action_name" />
```

- It's also possible declare the menuitem as a record of the `ir.ui.menu` model. In this case you should search the string `<field name="name">Human readable name</field>` in order to find the menu item

```xml
<record id="menu_human_readable_name" model="ir.ui.menu" >
    <field name="name">Human readable name</field>
    <field name="sequence" eval="10" />
    <field name="action" ref="action_name" />
    <field name="parent_id" ref="base.menu_custom" />
</record>
```

There is another option: you can go to the table where you can see or search the string of the menuitem in the interface: **Settings > Technical > User Interface > Menu items**

Maybe there are any other way to search them, but I am unaware of it.

I hope this helps you